# XPATH getting all tags without <script> and </script> tags

Tags: html, xpath, tags

I have some problem gettings all the html tags without `<script>` or `<script ... />` using Xpath.

For example, in this part of the HTML code, i want to remove :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=fr"/>
```

for this code

```
<li><!-- Search Google -->
<center>
                     <form action="http://www.google.fr/cse" id="cse-search-box" target="_blank">
                        <div>
                           <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-0959382714089534:mw3ssl65jk1"/>
                           <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1"/>
                           <input type="text" name="q" size="31"/>
                           <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Rechercher"/>
                        </div>
                     </form>
                     <script type="text/javascript"
                             src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=fr"/>
                  </center>
                  <!-- Search Google --></li>
```

I'm generating an xml file using Web-Harvest, and then i have to remove some specifics tags. 
I have try a lot of xpath (i'm working in the body of the html) :

- `//body//*[not(name() = 'script')]`
- `//body//*[not(self::script)]`
- `//body//*[not(starts-with(name(),'script'))]`
- `//body//*[not(contains(name(),'script'))]`

but it's not working.

Note that `//body//*[name() = 'script']` is working, but i want the opposite...

Do you have some ideas ?

Or more generaly, if you know how to remove all the `<script>` `<script/>` tag using Xpath, i'm also interest in :-)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation why this cannot be achieved using solely XPath and for a complete, short and easy XSLT solution. :)

Answer (score 4):

Well first of all XPath selects nodes in an existing document, it does not remove them. And your path `//body//*` you start with selects all child and descendant elements of the `body` element. Even if you now add a predicate like `//body//*[not(self::script)]` that path still selects elements like the `li` and the `center` element that are not themselves `script` elements but which contain a `script` element. So `//body//*[not(self::script)]` is the right approach not to select any non-`script` elements but it does not help if you want for instance the original `center` element with the `script` element being removed. That is not something pure XPath can do for you, you would need to move to XSLT to transform the document and that way remove any `script` elements.

Answer (score 3):

**XPath is just a *query* language for XML documents and as such it cannot alter in any way the XML document(s)** that is being queried.

The most convenient way to produce a new XML document that is different from the initial XML document is by using XSLT.

**This short and simple XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="script"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<li>
    <!-- Search Google -->
    <center>
        <form action="http://www.google.fr/cse"
              id="cse-search-box" target="_blank">
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="cx"
                value="partner-pub-0959382714089534:mw3ssl65jk1"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1"/>
                <input type="text" name="q" size="31"/>
                <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Rechercher"/>
            </div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=fr"/>
    </center>
    <!-- Search Google -->
</li>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<li><!-- Search Google -->
   <center>
      <form action="http://www.google.fr/cse" id="cse-search-box" target="_blank">
         <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-0959382714089534:mw3ssl65jk1"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1"/>
            <input type="text" name="q" size="31"/>
            <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Rechercher"/>
         </div>
      </form>
   </center><!-- Search Google -->
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first XPath from the question list is almost there:

- `//body//*[not(name() = 'script')]`

We can use `descendant` from [XPath Axes](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp), that supposed to be:

- `//body/descendant::*[not(name() = 'script')]`